# PHP Strip string of first url and report results

Tags: php, string, url, explode, strip

```
Russel Peter video: <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw">www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw</a> russel peters video blah blah. Turtles: <a href="http://turtles.com">turtles.com</a>
```

I have a string that contains text and and  tags with enclosed urls like the above example.

I want to strip the out ONLY the first  tag found

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw">www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw</a>
```

and from that, strip out the url inside the href="".

But... i also want to be able store the text around the  tag that is pulled out.

I'm looking for something like this as the end result after all the stripping:

```
$originalstring = "Russel Peter video: <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw">www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw</a> russel peters video blah blah. Turtles: <a href="http://turtles.com">turtles.com</a>";


$preurl = "Russel Peter video: ";

$atag = "<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw">www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw</a>";

$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw";

$afterurl = " russel peters video blah blah. Turtles: <a href="http://turtles.com">turtles.com</a>";
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

NOTE: i apologize if I've used the wrong terms.

Comment: Are you sure your formatted your post correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$orgstring = 'Russel Peter video: <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw">www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw</a> russel peters video blah blah. Turtles: <a href="http://turtles.com">turtles.com</a>';
$s = explode(":",$orgstring,2);
$preurl = $s[0];
$href= explode('href="',$s[1]);
$url=preg_replace("/\">.*/","",$href[1]);
$atag = preg_replace("/\">.*/","",$s[1]);
$after=explode("</a>",$orgstring,2);
$afterurl=$after[1];
print "\$preurl: $preurl\n";
print "\$url: $url\n";
print "\$atag: $atag\n";
print "\$afterurl: $afterurl\n";
```

output

```
$ php test.php
$preurl: Russel Peter video
$url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw
$atag:  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bP9tRhJRTw
$afterurl:  russel peters video blah blah. Turtles: <a href="http://turtles.com">turtles.com</a>
```

Comment: it looks good, but i accidentally put the code in <quotes> instead of <code>

Could you please please please update your original answer with the update variables?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode($tags, ' ', 2);` to get an array of two elements, the first being the first tag (the URL) and the second being all the other tags, if you know for sure they're always going to be space-separated.